# Does linkedin's dustJS works with mongoosejs object?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, dust.js, kraken.js

I've followed passportjs example in krakenjs.
https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-examples/blob/master/with.passport/lib/auth.js#L104

here's the code snippets I taken from the example.

```
exports.injectUser = function() {
    return function injectUser(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.locals.user = req.user;
        }
        next();
    }; 
};
```

when i tried to do {user}, it outputs all the fields in the user object, but when i do {user.fullname}, it outputs blank.

if i change the code to below,

```
exports.injectUser = function() {
    return function injectUser(req, res, next) {
        if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
            res.locals.user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.user)); 
        }
        next();
    };
};
```

It works fine when i do, {user.fullname}. Any idea why dustjs can't parse mongoose object?

I tried to check what's the instance type of the object, and it said [Object object]. But it wont work unless I explicitly JSON.stringify and JSON.parse it.

Any recommended solution or explanation why this is happening?

Comment: The above example repository is being deprecated in favor of a separate repo for each example instead. The new link would be: https://github.com/krakenjs/kraken-example-with-passport/blob/master/lib/auth.js#L104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. It's the issue with the dustjs-linkedin library. I was using 2.4.0. When I change it to 2.3.4, it works. Hope it helps others.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this -- for those wondering how to do this in a smooth way: set the version in "package.json" file and run "npm update dustjs-linkedin" afterwards!